# printing an array as a table in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

So, I am trying to print an array **Fi[rows][columns]** in a table format of 11 rows and 11 columns. The code I am using is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows ; i++){
    for (int j=0; j< columns; j++)
        std::cout << Fi[i][j]<<"\t";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

And my problem is, that the element printed on Fi[0][10] is not the one that it's supposed to be. Actually, if I simply print out

```
std::cout<< Fi[0][10];
```

I get the correct value.
Can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code shown looks fine. Your problem must be somewhere else. Please provide a [example] showing you populating the array with values and then outputting them. Hard-code the insertions, so we can all see what the values are. Then provide the expected output and the actual output as text in the question.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::setw` than tabs.  There is no standard spacing for tabs.  Common tab lengths are 2, 3, 4 and 8.  This is for fixed pitch fonts, the spacing will differ for variable pitched fonts.  Also, some consoles may use the definition "space to the next defined tab stop", which could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I changed the part `std::cout << "\n";` to `std::cout << std::endl;`

```
#include <array>
int main() {
    int rows = 4;
    int columns = 5;

    int my_array[rows][columns] = {{0,1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9},{10,11,12,13,13},{14,15,16,17,18}};

    for (int i = 0; i < rows ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j< columns; j++)
            std::cout << my_array[i][j]<<"\t";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the output:

```
0   1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  13  
14  15  16  17  18
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
int main(){
int num[3][3],i=0,sum=0;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        cin>>num[i][j];
        sum+=num[i][j];

}

}

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        cout<<num[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }

cout<<sum<<endl;
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to promote _learning_. For this reason, answers should not only include corrected or improved code, but also an explanation of _how_ and _why_ the implementation works. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful, and even if the code “should be self explanatory” adding explanation ensures _everyone_ can understand. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. From [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.